# Save mask to image (Python, OpenCV)

Tags: python, opencv, mask

I am using this code to create a mask which split every image in half (left-right).

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

image = cv2.imread('box.png')

h = image.shape[0]
w = image.shape[1]

mask_l = np.zeros(image.shape[:2], dtype="uint8")

roi = cv2.rectangle(mask_l, (w//2, 0), (0, h), 255, -1)  # LEFT MASK

masked_l = cv2.bitwise_and(image, image, mask=mask_l)
cv2.imshow("Left", masked_l)
cv2.waitKey(0)


mask_r = np.zeros(image.shape[:2], dtype="uint8")

cv2.rectangle(mask_r, (w//2, 0), (w, h), 255, -1)  # RIGHT MASK

masked_r = cv2.bitwise_and(image, image, mask=mask_r)
cv2.imshow("Right", masked_r)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

How can I save the visible part of the image to a ROI ? Possible, if the saved rectangle take the name as source image as part of filename.
Es: input --> box.png --> output --> box1.png, box2.png

Thanks

Comment: Crop the image and use `cv2.imwrite()`. Also update with sample input and sample output

Comment: As input/output you can use any image you want, there is no a specific one.

Comment: @ZdaR is this, how do I crop the visible area ? Using `cropped = image[w//2:0, 0:h]` doesn't work...

Answer (score 1):

I did it...

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import os

image = cv2.imread('box.png')

path, filename = os.path.split('box.png')
filename = (filename[:-4])

root_path = 'C:\\Users\\Link\\Desktop\\'

h = image.shape[0]
w = image.shape[1]

mask_l = np.zeros(image.shape[:2], dtype="uint8")

roi = cv2.rectangle(mask_l, (w//2, 0), (0, h), 255, -1)  # LEFT MASK

masked_l = cv2.bitwise_and(image, image, mask=mask_l)

list = ['a', 'b']

for i in enumerate(masked_l):
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(mask_l)
    roi_l = image[y:y + h, x:x + w]
    cv2.imwrite(root_path + str(filename) + '{}.png'.format(lista[0]), roi_l)

cv2.imshow("Left", roi_l)
cv2.waitKey(0)


h2 = image.shape[0]
w2 = image.shape[1]

mask_r = np.zeros(image.shape[:2], dtype="uint8")

cv2.rectangle(mask_r, (w2//2, 0), (w2, h2), 255, -1)  # RIGHT MASK

masked_r = cv2.bitwise_and(image, image, mask=mask_r)

for i_i in enumerate(masked_r):
    x2, y2, w2, h2 = cv2.boundingRect(mask_r)
    roi_r = image[y2:y2 + h2, x2:x2 + w2]

    cv2.imwrite(root_path + str(filename) + '{}.png'.format(lista[1]), roi_r)

cv2.imshow("Right", roi_r)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```